# tkinter, iterate through range to create multiple Labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create 46 labels, who's name is "cell_1......cell_n".

I tried to iterate use a for loop that adds 1 to n and concatenates a string with the next label name, then uses that string to build the next label.. But this does not work. Any suggestions?

```
            x_axis = 50
            y_axis = 50
            for t in range(46):
                 my_label = "self.cell_" + str(t)
                 my_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.grey_cell_image, background='light 
                 gray').place(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)
                 x_axis += 50
```

Comment: What exactly is it about this that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > `my_label = "self.cell_" + str(t)` will get replaced by `my_label = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.grey_cell_image, background='light gray').place(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)` because you replaced the data for `my_label`

So you should change the code into

```
            my_label = {} #create a dictionary of label
            x_axis = 50
            y_axis = 50
            for t in range(46):
                 my_label["self.cell_" + str(t)] = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.grey_cell_image, background='light gray').place(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)
                 x_axis += 50
```

Since you want to edit `label (n)`, you can use `my_label["self.cell_1"]` to call label 1, or if you are confused, use this code

```
            my_label = {} #create a dictionary of label
            x_axis = 50
            y_axis = 50
            for t in range(46):
                 my_label[t] = tk.Label(self.master, image=self.grey_cell_image, background='light gray').place(x=x_axis, y=y_axis)
                 x_axis += 50
```

And call `label (n)` by `my_label[n]`

Comment: There’s no reason to include “self” in the dictionary keys, and might be confusing for people who are just now learning python.

Comment: Thank you Fran, I did something similar to this in my code except I used a list. Bryan, good point, I will keep that in mind for future posts.

Comment: @BryanOakley and that's why I showed my second code :D